# PDO with sqlite wont insert anything

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a problem with PDO (i am new into this). My code is not able to insert anything into a table. I've tried every possible way i came up with to insert variables into the code (array, straight into the statement, with and without inserting id as NULL, etc.).

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:hpoi.sqlite');
$qry = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_hpoifinds (user, hpoiid) VALUES (?, ?)');
$qry->execute(array(NULL, $invoker, $id));
```

After this, the table stays empty...
When i try to use:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10 disk I/O error' in /DISK2/WWW/milerking.cz/dixi/projects/hpoi_plugin/hpoi.lib.php:39 Stack trace: #0 /DISK2/WWW/milerking.cz/dixi/projects/hpoi_plugin/hpoi.lib.php(39): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /DISK2/WWW/milerking.cz/dixi/projects/hpoi_plugin/hpoi.lib.php(23): hpoiright('dixxcz', 'riverofslime') #2 /DISK2/WWW/milerking.cz/dixi/projects/hpoi_plugin/hpoi.lib.php(11): hpoicheck('dixxcz', 'riverofslime') #3 /DISK2/WWW/milerking.cz/dixi/projects/hpoi_plugin/hpoi.lib.php(65): hpoi('dixxcz', 'riverofslime') #4 {main} thrown in /DISK2/WWW/milerking.cz/dixi/projects/hpoi_plugin/hpoi.lib.php on line 39
```

The full code can be found [here](http://dixi.milerking.cz/projects/hpoi_plugin/source.txt)

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake (not defining the first id), yet, the problem still remains. I've edited the post with the right type of error.

Comment: The exception looks like one of the values is not the right type for the column.

Comment: Did you var_dump the value from $row->id?

Comment: Okay, you've got now another exception. Can you read from table? Does php has permission to write into the sqlite file?

Comment: Yes and yes, the code works perfectly, excpet for the insert. Permissions are set to 777 on the database file.

Answer (score 1):

You prepared with 2 placeholders, but you passed 3 parameters to `execute()` the numbers must match:

```
$qry = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_hpoifinds (user, hpoiid) VALUES (?, ?)');
$qry->execute(array($invoker, $id));
```